# Using selenium.webdriver for a more responsive Cherrypy development environment

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, cherrypy, web-development-server

I've been trying to use the selenium module to open a browser when the cherrypy server starts.

I want it to reload the page with cherrypy.Autoreload so i dont have to use the mouse.

As a cherrypy plugin, if it starts too early the server doesn't respond and it throws an error ending the session.

I need an after_server_start event or something.
Any advice??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured this out somewhat.
I made a daemon server using cherryd:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import cherrypy,time,os,signal

class CpIde():
    def __init__(self):pass

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):return "hello there"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def open(self):
        if hasattr(self,'driver'):
            try:self.driver.quit()
            except:
                self.driver.service.process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
        self.driver=webdriver.Firefox()
        return "Opening FF"

    @cherrypy.expose 
    def start(self):
        try:
            self.driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
        except:pass
        finally:
            self.driver.execute_script("""
            document.body.innerHTML="Just one second"; 
            window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(false)},300) """
)
        return "starting FF"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def close(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        del self.driver
        return 'Closing FF'

    @cherrypy.expose 
    def refresh(self):
        self.driver.execute_script("""
            document.body.innerHTML="Just one second"; 
            window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(false)},300) """)
        return "restarting"

cherrypy.tree.mount(CpIde(),'/')
```

Then i made a plugin that makes requests to it:

```
import cherrypy,time,os
from cherrypy.process import wspbus, plugins
import requests as r


def command(method):
    addr='http://127.0.0.1:3131/'
    r.get(addr+method)

class CpIdePlugin(plugins.SimplePlugin):
    def __init__(self,bus):
        plugins.SimplePlugin.__init__(self,bus)
        self.bus.log('Init plug')
        DriveId=os.getenv('CherryDrive')
        self.running=False
        if DriveId:
            self.running=True
        else:
            command('open')
            os.putenv('CherryDrive','True')


    def start(self):
        self.bus.log('Running FF plugin')
        if self.running:
            self.refresh()
        else:
            command('start')

    def refresh(self):#need to make a channel i think
        self.bus.log("Reload via bus")
       command('refresh')
```

It ties into my main app with:

```
import cpideplugin
class root:pass

cherrypy.tree.mount(root(),"/")

cpideplugin.CpIdePlugin(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()
cherrypy.engine.start()#the pubsub engine
cherrypy.server.start()#an html server channel on the engine
cherrypy.engine.block()
cpideplugin.command('close')
```

This way the selenium driver doesn't refresh with the Autoreload and i can work freely from vim.  This is not perfect code and i would appreciate any recommendations.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `start` phase of the cherrypy engine (bus).

```
import webbrowser                                                               

import cherrypy                                                                 
from cherrypy.process.plugins import SimplePlugin                               

class Root:                                                                     

    @cherrypy.expose                                                            
    def default(self):                                                          
        return "Hello World!"                                                   

class OpenBrowser(SimplePlugin):                                                

    def start(self):                                                            
        self.bus.log("Opening browser")                                         
        webbrowser.open('http://localhost:8080/')                               

OpenBrowser(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()                                        
cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

For more information: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#engine-as-a-pubsub-bus

Comment: That works well but it opens a tab on every edit.  Eventually i have to close them or do it routinely.

Comment: Yeah the `webbrowser` part was a demo, I focused on the way to run something when the restart happen, you have to implement the Selenium code to do the reload the browser (one that was created with the webdriver).